# The existence of some vector NOT perpendicular to a given set of vectors

Tags: geometry

Let $S=\left\{\mathbf{q}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{q}_{m}\right\}$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and satisfy $\mathbf{q}^{T}_{i}\mathbf{q}_{i}=1$ for all $i \in[1, m]$. I would like to know the existence of some vector $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that, for all $i \in[1, m], \mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{q}_{i}$ are not orthogonal. Is there such a theorem regarding the existence of $\mathbf u$?

Thanks.

Comment: By $\mathbf v_i$ you mean $\mathbf q_i$? - Also, what have you tried?

Comment: For each $\mathbf{q}_i$, the set of vectors perpendicular to it is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. A finite union of hyperplanes has measure zero, so it can never be all of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Therefore you can find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which lies outside the union of these hyperplanes and this vector has therefore non-zero projection onto any of the vectors $\mathbf{q}_i$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{v}_i$ is a typo. And I have corrected it.

Comment: Just take $u=\sum_{i=1}^mq_i$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe that works only in general if the $\mathbf{q}_i$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @Tychonoff3000 Thanks, your answer is clear and very helpful!